# How do you pass event to a setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I currently have:

```
var content = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
var myButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".more-button");

function enableContent(evt){
// remove class d-none so it can appear
    content[evt.currentTarget.param].className = content[evt.currentTarget.param].className.replace(/\bd-none\b/g, "");
}

for(var i=0; i<myButtons.length; i++){
    myButtons[i].addEventListener("click", enableContent);
    myButtons[i].param = i;
}
```

Each myButton has it's own content. I'm trying to make content appear slowly when myButton is clicked like so:

```
for(var i=0; i<myButtons.length; i++){
        myButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){setTimeout(enableContent, 2000, evt)}));
        myButtons[i].param = i;
}
```

But it doesn't work, there is a problem with the parameter evt. How do I pass in evt to setTimeout?

Comment: `addEventListener("click", function(evt){setTimeout(enableContent, 2000, evt)})`?

Comment: Do you need an animation of button appearing or just a delay?

Comment: If I understood your idea correctly you need next: ```myButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {setTimeout(function(){ enableContent(event); }, 2000); });```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making solution easier by setting the `setTimeout` inside the `enableConent` directly

```js
function enableContent(evt){
// remove class d-none so it can appear
    setTimeout( () => {

         content[evt.currentTarget.param].className = 
           content[evt.currentTarget.param].className.replace(/\bd-none\b/g, "");
    
    }, 2000);

}
```

But if you need to learn why the event is not being passed to the `enableContent` event handler we need to know how `setTimeout` and function binding works.

setTimeout take a callback (fancy word for passing a function to another function) and a delay time(that guarantees at least `x` time before calling the callback function.

so using `setTimeout` should be used like

```js
setTimeout( enableContent, 2000 );
```

yet this code won't pass the event so we need to bind the function `enableContent` with the `event object` so when the event handler is called the function know and access the `event object` properly

```js
myButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){

    setTimeout( enableContent.bind(event), 2000);

});
```

binding in `js` has many types, implicit, explicit, hard, & new binding. using `bind` function bind the `enalbeConent` with the `event` and return a new function that is `hard bound` with the event object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event (evt) to the function itself, and I think maybe you are moving the wrong way using the **setTimeout**, maybe you don't need to use a **setTimeout**? You can use css **animation** or **transition** with ***-delay** properties?

But if you are using **setTimeout**, you need to clear timeout after every click using the **clearTimeout** method:

```
myButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
   if(evt.currentTarget.timer) {
       clearTimeout(e.currentTarget.timer);
   }
   evt.currentTarget.timer = setTimeout(enableContent, 2000);
}));
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6kcq2ma8/

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy!

window.addEventListener("load", (event)=> {

```
let setTimeoutHandler = (event) =>{
    console.log(event);
}

setTimeout(()=>{
    setTimeoutHandler(event);
}, 1000);
```

});